# RecyclerView item fills the whole screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-7.0-nougat

I have a Recyclerview which is working fine with the **Android version 23** but if i am running the same code with the **Android version 25** then the whole screen is occupied by the single item.

Initially the list looks fine where the item height is wrap content. But as i scroll the whole screen is occupied by single item.

Below is my layout containing RecyclerView:

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your recyclerview item xml.

Comment: Post item layout which you are inflating in recyclerview. Then only we will be able to help you more precisely.

Comment: Set wrap_content for your inflating layout height.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48310052/6021740

Answer (score 10):

Your Recyclerview code is ok. 
if you are using TextView or else in your iteam_raw.xml then make sure you give 
"wrap_content"

iteam_raw.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please use recyclerview item's main layout height "wrap_content".

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the all UI element you are using in ViewHolder must have height to wrap content and if you are using cardview as parent container make that height also wrap_content.

Answer (score 1):

change the `layout_height` property from `match_parent` to `wrap_content` or some size in your linearlayout.

example:

```
<LinearLayout  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="120dp" <-- **change in height**
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Answer (score -1):

Set layout height and width to 0dp

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```